# Ratio of solutions to two heat equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, asymptotics, parabolic-pde, heat-equation

Let $u(x,t)$ and $v(x,t)$ respectively solve the two one-dimensional heat equations with different (real) diffusion coefficients on the same domain $D$ and the same initial & boundary conditions,  i.e.,
$$u_t(x,t) = \alpha \ u_{xx}(x,t), \quad v_t(x,t) = \beta \ v_{xx}(x,t), \quad (x,t) \in D $$

For simplicity, say $D$ is the domain $t \in [0,1]$, $x \leq c(t)$ where $c \in C^\infty[0,1]$,

Initial condition: $u(x,0) = v(x,0) = f(x) \in C^2$ with $f(x) \leq \exp\{-x^2\}$,

and boundary condition  $u(t,c(t)) = v(t,c(t)) \equiv 0$.

**Question:** What can be said about the asymptotic behaviour of the ratio $u/v$ when $\alpha / \beta \to 0$ or $\alpha / \beta \to \infty$?

If $c = 0$, (i.e $D$ is a rectangle), we have closed form solutions $u$ and $v$ but I'm looking for more general results.

Comment: Are there some comparison theorems of this type?